# Is there a way I can transform a button in a circle button with animation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I found out that animation in the internet and was wondering if I can recreate it.

[image]

So far what I could achive is the animation of the button to scale.

[image]

Code:

```
      if (Button1.ScaleX < 1)
      {
        await Button1.ScaleXTo(1);
      }
      else
      {

        await Button1.ScaleXTo(0.25);
      }
```

Button:

```xml
<Button x:Name="Button1" Grid.Row="1" Clicked="Button1_Clicked" AnchorX="0.5" WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="40" BorderRadius="20"/>
```

My question is how can I make the button become a circle after the scale?

Comment: I want the button to be the same size so, I don't need to scale Y property, about the border radius probably I need to scale it, the problem is I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your border radius is already set to 50% of the height and width after it's scaled down, all you need to do animate the width of the button.

**XAML**

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button
        x:Name="Button1"
        BorderRadius="20"
        Clicked="Button1_Clicked"
        HeightRequest="40"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        WidthRequest="150" />
</StackLayout>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var changeWidthAnimation = Button1.Width == 150
        ? new Animation(b => Button1.WidthRequest = b, 150, 40)
        : new Animation(b => Button1.WidthRequest = b, 40, 150);

    changeWidthAnimation.Commit(this, nameof(changeWidthAnimation), 16, 150, Easing.Linear);
}
```

**Explanation**

This method runs on each button click.
It's defining an animation based on the current button width.
If the current button width is 150, then setup an animation to change the width from 150 to 40. Otherwise, make the animation go from 40 to 150.
Then fire off the animation over a period of 150 milliseconds.
Since your border radius is already 20 (50% of 40), you end with a nice round button.

Answer (score 1):

You can update CornerRadius and WidthRequest properties using the Animation.WithConcurrent to do both animations at the same time. this is a small sample.

this is the Xaml code.

```
      <Button
            x:Name="animatedButton"
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            Clicked="AnimatedButton_Clicked"
            CornerRadius="0"
            HeightRequest="40"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            WidthRequest="100" />
```

This is the .cs code

```
    private void AnimatedButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateAnimation();
    }

    private void CreateAnimation()
    {
        var animation = new Animation();

        animation.WithConcurrent(
           (f) => animatedButton.CornerRadius = (int)f, 0, 20, Easing.Linear, 0, 1);

        animation.WithConcurrent(
          (f) => animatedButton.WidthRequest = (int)f, 100, 40, Easing.Linear, 0, 1);

        animatedButton.Animate("CreateAnimation", animation, 16, 500, easing: Easing.Linear);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing those two animations, the difference is in corner radius. If you set it to the right level (half of height) and small width to be the same as height it will work.